# Retrieving paypal plan through SDK gives error code 400 - No Request Payload

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal, sdk

I am trying to GET a plan through the latest Github Paypal SDK using the sample script of the SDK. When calling the API it throws:

```
'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-0B085781ML2192537TXPEZ6I.'
```

These are the lines of concern in the log file:

```
[18-05-2016 12:26:16] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-0B085781ML2192537TXPEZ6I
[18-05-2016 12:26:16] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Invalid or no certificate authority found - Retrying using bundled CA certs file
[18-05-2016 12:26:18] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : DEBUG: Request Headers     : GET /v1/payments/billing-plans/P-0B085781ML2192537TXPEZ6I HTTP/1.1, Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com, Accept: */*, Content-Type: application/json, User-Agent: PayPalSDK/PayPal-PHP-SDK 1.7.1 (platform-ver=5.6.12; bit=32; os=Windows_NT_6.2; machine=i586; crypto-lib-ver=1.0.1p; curl=7.42.1), Authorization: Bearer ..., , 
[18-05-2016 12:26:18] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : DEBUG: No Request Payload
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
[18-05-2016 12:26:18] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 400
[18-05-2016 12:26:18] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : DEBUG: Response Headers    : HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request, Date: Tue, 17 May 2016 22:26:19 GMT, Server: Apache, PROXY_SERVER_INFO: host=slcsbplatformapiserv3002.slc.paypal.com;threadId=311, Paypal-Debug-Id: dc99bbb98dc5e, CORRELATION-ID: dc99bbb98dc5e, Content-Language: *, Connection: close, Connection: close, Paypal-Debug-Id: dc99bbb98dc5e, Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dplatformapiserv%26TIME%3D2342140759%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3D; Expires=Tue, 17 May 2016 22:56:20 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT, Vary: Authorization, Content-Length: 0, Content-Type: text/xml, , 
[18-05-2016 12:26:18] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : ERROR: Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-0B085781ML2192537TXPEZ6I. 
[18-05-2016 12:26:18] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : DEBUG:
```

From what i understood from the log entries, i have tried so far: swapping certs, turning off SSL verify in curl part all together and different active plan ids of course.

BTW All other calls to Paypal return data as expected. It is just the get plan call.

I use XAMPP localhost on Windows if that is of any help.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Sooo.. it was my clumsiness i suppose  :)

The plan ids that end in above error did not exist anymore or had the state deleted. Anyhow, they were not reachable anymore. So paypal sent that error code 400.

**Note:** This also happens on a plan update call if the state is not changing. I.e. you try to send a new state of 'ACTIVE' while the plan your trying to change already has state active. The same error code 400 will be thrown.
I know it does not make sense to activate an activated plan but sometimes if you forget to check your code, such errors can become very misleading.